# Why nth-child is not working as expected?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wanna position image which has `photo` class. However, `nth-child` is not working on that element. I looked for many solutions, but it couldn't be solved!

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.irene {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 60vw;
}

.irene-img {
  position: relative;
}

.irene-img::after {
  content: ' ';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #2ebce2;
}

.irene-title {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: -10%;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-size: 10rem;
}

.irene-title span {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.single__detail__spec {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2;
  top: 35%;
  right: 10%;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.single__detail__spec span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.single__detail__saying {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.photo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}

.photo:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <base href="https://raw.githack.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/html/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/default.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="irene">
      <div class="irene-img">
        <img src="../images/about-irene.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <p class="irene-title">IRENE <span>배주현</span></p>
    </div>
    <p class="single__detail__spec">
      <span>생일.</span> 1991.03.29<br/>
      <span>별명.</span> 배추, 현이, 엔딩요정<br/>
      <span>취미.</span> 다리미질, 빨래<br/>
      <span>혈액형.</span> A형
    </p>
    <p class="single__detail__saying">
      "lorem ipsum"
    </p>
  </div>
  <img class="photo" src="../images/photo-irene1.jpg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

Why `nth-child` of `photo` is not working? How to handle it?

Comment: Your image doesn't (and can't) have any child elements, what are you expecting `nth-child` to find?

Comment: I wanna position image to left-top of body. I understood `nth-child` is for nth element of specific element. Is it wrong?

Comment: please provide the screenshot of what you want as output. @Haram Bae and img tag not having child so nth-child of .photo is not working. you direct apply css to .photo.

Comment: the index in `nth-child` starts from 1, your `img` tag is second child of it's parent try using `nth-child(2)`

Comment: If you want to maintain the indexes specific to img tags, you can use `nth-of-type` instead

Comment: It was solved by make `div` above img! I understood about `nth-child`. Thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused between [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) and [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

`nth-child(n)`: Selects the matching element that comes after `n-1` elements in the same parent, it doesn't care whether those elements match the same selector or not, it only cares about position.

`nth-of-type(n)`: Selects the matching element that comes after `n-1` elements that matches the same selector in the same parent.

There are 2 possible solutions for your problem

1. `img:nth-child(2)`
2. `img:nth-of-type(1)`

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered, but i would like to add something to it:
.photo:nth-child(1) would normally be written as .photo:first-child.

As was said, in this case it doesn't work because the element with the class 'photo' is not the first child of it's parent. The selector .photo:first-child (which would be the correct choice anyway) as well as the selector .photo:nth-child(1) will look for the element with the class .photo which is the first child of it's parent. If there are not elements with that class, whilst also being first child of their parents, the style won't be applied.

If you wanted to select by type, as in, select the first element that comes up with that class, no matter it's position to it's parent, the selector .photo:nth-of-type(1) should be used.

If you wanted to select the element according to it's position to it's parent, it should be .photo:nth-child(2) since the element with the class .photo is the second in relation to it's parent.

Here is a guide towards :nth-child(n) which i found very explanatory. https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Here is a guide for :nth-of-type https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/ which is also quick and easy to understand. I hope i helped!